# How to dynamically create multiple inputs and then can get their values in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2.

I want to dynamically create multiple inputs, and then provide ways to get their value by using `[(ngModel)]="input1"` or other ways:

I thought about using `[hidden]`, but since I don't know the exact number of inputs the user wants, so I asked about how I can dynamically create inputs.

**html**

```
<button (click)="addInput()">Add Input</button>
```

**ts**

```
addInput() {
    // first time click, add <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="input1"/>
    // second time click, add <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="input2"/>
    // third time click, add <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="input3"/>
    // forth, fifth, etc.
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create an array of objects.  Push onto the array when you want a new input.  Use `NgFor` to generate the form elements.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<button (click)="addInput()">Add Input</button>
  <div *ngFor="let input of inputs">
    <input [(ngModel)]="input.value">
  </div>
  {{inputs | json}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
  inputs = [{value: "first"}];
  addInput()  {
    this.inputs.push({value: ''});
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xw43lC7zpVF5rzNQ3ePS?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: This works. However, I'd like to use the same approach for creating select/option setup. Is it possible? I'm trying from different angles but only get a bunch of humongous errors about "no value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute"...

Answer (score 2):

You can use addControl on your Form object:

```
this.yourForm.addControl("inputName", new Control);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/MahOzQqkyv613N1NtElF?p=preview